# Celebrity using stack in C language

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, data-structures, stack

For this question you have to take a 2D array or matrix and using Stack function push and pop , find the celebrity member in the matrix. Only using C language

Here is my code that I have tried

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define size 4

int stack[size];
int top=-1;

void push(int val){
    if(top==size-1){
        printf("stack is already full,error\n");
    
    }else{
        top++;
        stack[top]=val;
    }
}

int pop(){
    if(top==-1)
    {
        printf("underflow condition");
    }
    else{
        return stack[top--];
    }
}
int CelebrityProblem(int arr[4][4]) 
{ 
    
  int i;
    for ( i = 0; i<4; i++) 
        push(i); 
  
    while (size>1) 
    { 
        int temp1 =stack[top];
        pop();

        int temp2 = stack[top];
        pop();

        if (arr[temp1][temp2]) 
           push(temp2);

        else
           push(temp1);
    } 
    
    int potential_celeb=stack[top];
int j;
    for( j=0; j<4; j++)
    {
        if(j==stack[top])
            continue;
        
        if(arr[potential_celeb][j]==1)
            return -1;
            
        if(arr[j][potential_celeb]!=1)
            return -1;
        
    }
  
    return potential_celeb; 
} 
int main(){
    int arr[4][4]={ {0,0,1,1},
                    {1,0,1,0},
                    {0,1,0,0},
                    {0,1,1,0} };
                    
      int celebrity = CelebrityProblem(arr);

    if(celebrity == -1)
        printf("No Celebrity Exists!");
    else
       printf("Celebrity is Person Number %d",celebrity);
    return 0;

}
```

According to my approach I am getting output as conditionunderflow . can anyone please help me to find where i'm doing the mistake .

Comment: The `while (size>1)` looks suspicious (`size` is a defined constant that doesn't change). Did you mean `while (top>1)`?

Comment: Obviously, the celebrity in the Matrix is Keanu Reeves...  Or maybe you have in mind a different, graph-related definition that you didn't bother to state?